# How can I check if an object is a file with isinstance()?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

How can I check if an object is a file?

```
>>> f = open("locus.txt", "r")
>>> type(f)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> isinstance(f, TextIOWrapper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(f, TextIOWrapper)
NameError: name 'TextIOWrapper' is not defined
>>> isinstance(f, _io.TextIOWrapper)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(f, _io.TextIOWrapper)
NameError: name '_io' is not defined
>>> isinstance(f, _io)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(f, _io)
NameError: name '_io' is not defined
>>>
```

I have the variable `f` that is a text file.  When I print the type of `f` the Python3 interpreter shows '_io.TextIOWrapper', but if I check it with `isinstance()` function throws exception: NameError.

Comment: `_io` and `TextIOWrapper` are not global variables, so you cannot use them directly. Hence the error.

Comment: I wonder how `2to3` handles this?

Comment: @smci: I am pretty sure it doesn't. The `fix_types` fixer even has the `FileType` mapping *commented out*.

Comment: Is there any good 2-to-3 guide on how to port type-checking?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`_io` is the C implementation for the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). Use [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) for direct subclasses, after importing the module:

```
>>> import io
>>> f = open("tests.py", "r")
>>> isinstance(f, io.IOBase)
True
```

Comment: If I want to close the range for only text files can I use `io.TextIOBase`?

Comment: Yup, see the [class hierarchy section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy), that's what the base classes are there for (they are ABCs, so they test for *functionality*, not just subclasses).